# Storing file names in an array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to store the file names in some directory in an array. I have the following script:

```
files= Dir.glob('C:\Users\Abder-Rahman\Desktop\drugsatfda\*.*')
files.each do |filename|
  contents = IO.read(filename)
  puts contents
end
exit
```

But, I don't know why it doesn't work. What could I be missing?

Comment: drugsatfda data on the desktop?

Comment: @texasbruce Yes, it is on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not described in [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob), but `Dir.glob` doesn't throw any exception in case you provided invalid path - it will return just empty array.

```
files = Dir.glob("./an/imaginary/directory/that/doesnt/exist/*")
# => []
```

Please, make sure, that the path you've provided both - exists, and has any files.